# Laravel 5.1: How to execute a block of transactions?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have the follow relationships:
A **Student** has a "one-to-one" relationship with a **Person**. A Person has a "many-to-many" relationship with **Address**.

I want to persist the data: first create the Person, after create the Addresses and then create the Student.

But I want to rollback the transations if any error occur during the persistence in any of these tables. Ex.: If I save the Person and the Addresses, and the Student fails, I want to rollback everything.

How to handle this with Eloquent?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please show your attempts and the results?

Comment: @katzenhut, I will try and give the feedback. But I asked about Eloquent because in my project we do decided not to use DB facade. We use only functions from Eloquent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Laravel provides vary simple way to handle this kind of situation.

```
DB::transaction(function () {
    //all your codes 
});
```

From laravel Documentation :

To run a set of operations within a **database transaction**, 
you may use the **transaction method** on the **DB facade**. If an **exception** is **thrown** within the transaction Closure, the transaction **will automatically be rolled back**. If the Closure executes **successfully**, the transaction **will automatically be committed**. You don't need to worry about manually rolling back or committing while using the transaction method.

Also if you want to do it manually , you can do it using

```
    DB::beginTransaction();
    //your codes
    DB::commit();
```

To learn more about transactions, read official document [Here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/database)

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to do it with Eloquent?

Comment: @AndrezaVieira the solution provided *is* Eloquent. Eloquent is wrapping the classes used by the DB facade.

Comment: I will try and give the feedback :) Thanks.

Comment: I tried and I noted that the data returned from the request have a different structure and I do not know how to acess the fields. I have the function `create(array $data)` that receive the request $data and then I can acess any field. Ex.: `$data['person_name']`. But if I put my entire code inside the `DB::transaction(function ($data) {...});´ closure, the $data has a different structure.

Comment: I tried the first solution and it worked. If we need to use some variable inside the transaction closure, we have to do this way: `\DB::transaction(function () use ($data) { //my code... });`. So, I can use the variable `$data` normally.